# What causes a type error like this in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, typeerror

I'm playing with Haskell to evaluate simple limits with tables of values.  I have the following function defined:

```
f :: (Integral a) => a -> a
f x = div 1 $ subtract 6 x
```

and in GHCI, I `let leftSide = [5.90, 5.91..5.99]` and `let rightSide = [6.10,6.09..6.01]`, then:

```
GHCI> map f leftSide
```

Which barfs up this error:

```
<interactive>:50:5
  No instance for (Integral Double) arising from a use of `f'
  Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Integral Double)
  In the first argument of `map', namely `f'
  In the expression: map f leftSide
  In an equation for `it': it = map f leftSide
```

Changing my type declaration for f to `(Integral Double a) => a -> a` makes the compiler complain about how `Integral' is applied to too many type arguments.  What's going on here?

Comment: Perhaps because `Double` is not Integral?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just tried the wrong *division* - you really want `(/)` not `div`...

your problem is that `div` which demands an `Integral` type (for example an `Integer`):

```
Prelude> :t div
div :: Integral a => a -> a -> a
```

but then you use it with a `Fractional` (`6.10`, ...) by `map`ing it over your `leftSide` and `rightSide`

now GHCi defaults this to `Double` - but `Double` is not an instance of `Integral` - this is exactly what Haskell is complaining about.

---

the thing you tried does not work and I guess you wanted to write `(Integral a, Double a) => ...` but in the end (if it would work - it does not since `Double` is type and not a type-class) it would be the same as saying `f :: Double -> Double` anyway - which would get you the error again (as there is no `div` for `Double`)

To make it short: **use `(/)` instead of `div`** and it should work:

```
f :: Fractional r => r -> r
f x = (1 /) $ subtract 6 x
```

here is your first example:

```
Prelude> let leftSide = [5.90, 5.91..5.99]
Prelude> map f leftSide
[-10.000000000000036,-11.111111111111128
,-12.49999999999999,-14.285714285714228
,-16.66666666666653,-19.999999999999716
,-24.999999999999424,-33.33333333333207
,-49.999999999996625,-99.99999999998437]
```

---

btw: you can make this *shorter* if you use point-free:

```
f = (1 /) . (6 -)
```

or a bit cleaner / more readable if you write it out

```
f x = 1 / (6 - x)
```

Comment: Isn't `div 1` supposed to become `(1 /)` (or better yet, `recip`)?

Comment: doh ... of course (and indeed I should just copy&paste - as you can see the snippet I used in GHCi used the right definition :( ...

Comment: for *me* `recip` has the same problem as `subtract` - IMO if you do calculations the math-style formula is cleaner than *spelling* it out - but that' s just my taste of things

Comment: @Carsten: what do you mean by that? I'd say `subtract` is merely an ugly workaround for the inability to write right sections of `-`. OTOH, `negate` and `recip` actually capture the mathematical concept of inverse elements, which is in a sense more fundamental than `a/b` or `a-b`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I was talking about the situation here - I find `1 / (6-x)` more *natural* than `recip . subtract 6` and I would prefer `(1 /)` over `recip` too - but as I said that's just my taste

Comment: @leftaroundabout btw: *more fundamental* could be debated as you usually construct the integers out of the naturals by using equivalence classes of pairs which are indeed the later `a-b` - same is true for the rationals out of the integers ^^ ... which is of course completely OT here

Comment: Purely as a matter of curiosity, why are `div` and `(/)` different operations in Haskell?

Comment: the first is integer division (you typically use this with `mod` - there is even a combined `divMod` - as in division with remainder ... and there is also `quotRem` this pair handles negative numbers diverentlly) - the other is what you would use with floating point / decimal numbers

Comment: so it's `5 = 1 * 4 + 1` vs. `5 = 1.25 * 4` ( ``5 `div` 4 = 1`` vs `5 / 4 = 1.25`) - so the operations are different!

Comment: I was perhaps a little too ambiguous. What I meant was, why is it that Haskell has one operation to work exclusively on integers and another to work with floating points?

Comment: it's not exclusive for integers - it's for every `Integral` type (it's mostly  [euclidean domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain)) - and as I said: it makes sense since the operations are different - one will be the inverse operation to multiplication and the other will usually be not